# how can i scale down my coordinates using map to fit on the canvas

Tags: p5.js

I am trying to recreate the TSP and I am trying to read data from a file and draw ellipses at the coordinates from the file. I have achieved this but now I am having an issue where some of the coordinates are off the canvas. I know I need to scale down the max X and max Y values to achieve this but I'm unsure of how to approach this.  I have attempted to try this myself but I am lost atm please help!

see attached code below.

```
let loadTSP;
let loadSol;
let City = new Array();
citySize = 12;
let minX, maxX, minY, maxY;
let mulX,mulY;

var myData = [{id: [0]},{xCords: [1]},{yCords: [2]}];
function preload() {
  loadTSP = loadStrings("TSP_EUC_Problems/berlin52.tsp");
  // loadTSP = loadStrings("TSP_EUC_Problems/a280.tsp"); 
  // loadTSP = loadStrings("TSP_EUC_Problems/ch150.tsp"); 
  // loadSol = loadSol(solutionFileName);
  // loadSol = loadStrings(solutionFileName);
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  background(255, 200, 200);


  coords = new Array(myData.length);
  showLoadedTSP();
  showSolution();
//   minX = myData[i][1], myData[i][2];
//   maxX = myData[i][1], myData[i][2];
//   minY = myData[i][1], myData[i][2];
//   maxY = myData[i][1], myData[i][2];



//   if (coords[i].x > maxX) {
//     maxX = coords[i].x
//   }
//   if (coords[i].x < minX) {
//     minX = coords[i].x
//   }
//   if (coords[i].y > maxY) {
//     maxY = coords[i].y
//   }
//   if (coords[i].y < minY) {
//     minY = coords[i].y
//   }
// }
 
// let coords = map(maxX, 0,maxY) 


function showLoadedTSP() {
  loadTSP.splice(0, 6); // removes first 6 lines of file 
  loadTSP.splice(loadTSP.length - 1, 1)
  for (let i = 0; i < loadTSP.length; i++) { // loops through the length of the tsp file 
    myData[i] = split(loadTSP[i], ' ');  //
   
    if (myData[i].length > 3) { // if more than 3 parameters in file it removes excess 
      let voidSpaces = myData[i].length - 3;
      myData[i].splice(0, voidSpaces);
    
    }
    for(let i= 0; i < myData.length; i++){
      stroke(255);
      strokeWeight(2);
      fill("blue");
        ellipse(myData[i][1], myData[i][2], citySize); // draws the ellipse from the x, y coordinate
    } 
   // use map function to scale 


  }
  console.log(myData);
}

function showSolution() {

}

function draw() {

  // berlin52
  text("berlin52", 100,80);
  text("Berlin", 100,100);
  text("52 cities", 100,120);
//ludwig a280
  // text("a280", 100,80);
  // text("Ludwig", 100,100);
  // text("280 cities", 100,120);

  // ch150
// text("ch150", 100,80);
//   text("churritz", 100,100);
//   text("150 cities", 100,120);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the array and find the maxX the minX, maxY and minY. Then run through eachobject and map their x and y, like this:

```
coords[i].x = map(coords[i].x,minX,maxX,0,width);
coords[i].y = map(coords[i].y,minY,maxY,0,height);
```